# Check for space form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/1Lo7ag21/6/

I have a name input where I would like the first and second name

I'm trying to validate a name field by checking for a space.

How can I check that the field contains a space and display the alert if it doesn't

```
    $('button').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var name = $('#name').val();

        if(name.length == 0 && name.indexOf(' ') === -1){
            alert('Add first and last name with a space');
        }

    })
```

Comment: Your condition is interpreted as `if name is empty and space is not found`. See the problem? You could as well write 2 validation rules, one of empty name (first) and the other for the required space (second).

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethong like this:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
name =       name.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"") ;  // strip any leading or trailing spaces
name  = name.replace(/\s+/g," ");  // remove multiple intermediate spaces
if (!/(^[A-Za-z]\s[A-Za-z-   ']$)/.test(name)) {   // first and second names separated by a space, allow for hyphen and apostrophe
   alert ("You must enter your first name and last name separated by a space");
}
```

Comment: Danis, this looks like it should work but it doesn't - http://jsfiddle.net/1Lo7ag21/20/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've nearly got it, but your condition is a little off.

```
if(name.length == 0 && name.indexOf(' ') === -1){
```

You're checking that the name length is *both* 0 (empty string) *and* does not contain a space. You probably meant to use `||` (or) here.

```
if(name.length === 0 || name.indexOf(' ') === -1){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1Lo7ag21/13/

Comment: @Danis The version you linked does not appear to work. It still has the `&&` in there. Does not alert if you enter text w/out a space. Edit: Ok, now you just modified your link to point to your own answer's solution. Add that to your answer, not mine.